# fitting a image in a arbitary shape using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to fit this image into a arbitrary shape. for creating a photo frame.

[image: image to be placed inside frame]

And this is the frame

[image: frame in which photo is to be fit]

My Question is how to place the color image in the white space. that to in such a way that if the location or dimension or shape of white space changes the image will adjust itself accordingly ?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways of mapping a rectangle to a sphere. You should be more precise of what you expect.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers Sir  I need to resize the color image in such a way that, it can be placed inside the white space in the bw image(the frame).

Comment: I see two possible meanings: do you want to scale the image so that the entire rectangle fits inside the circle? Or do you want to scale the image so that it's smaller dimension is the same size as the max dimension of the mask and then place it inside the mask (so it resizes and crops the image with the mask)? I'm assuming the second option. I'm assuming also that you want the head to be placed in the center of the circle, *not* the center of the actual white shape which is a cut-off circle. For this you would need a more sophisticated pipeline, so what other kind of shapes would be possible?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Sir, Yes I need the second condition (resize and crop the image.), but I need the head to be placed in center of the actual white shape the cut-off circle. And if the location of the circle changes, the head should adjust itself to and relocate itself to that new position.